# How to use "such" and" so much"?

Tags: conjunctions

Would you please show me the ***difference*** in ***meaning***  between them?

> A. She worked so that she can earned twice as much as she used to earned.
>
> B. She worked such that she can earned twice as much as she used to earned.

Comment: I have never seen *can earned*! Also, there is no "so much" in your sentences.

Comment: Ahmad, although I have sometimes some mistakes or typoes, almost always many of the regular users here can understand most of my questions.

Comment: As a friendly advice, your sentence may imply that you mean those who are not native are not educated or intelligent, you'd better don't label any people with specific attributes. Anyone could be educated or not, no matter whether he is native or not.

Comment: @Ahmad - Just some friendly advice: don't say ["As a friendly advice."](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/103619/is-just-a-friendly-advice-grammatical)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*So* emphasizes the degree or amount of something, then the sentence A could mean:

> She worked **so much** that she could earn twice as much as she used to.

*Such* points to the manner she worked, she may didn't work much, but

> Her work was such (in a way) that she could earn twice as much as she used to.

Comment: nima, "can earned" is incorrect.  You will notice in d_bester's answer that he has changed it to "can earn" which is correct.  If you actually want the past tense, you would need to use "could earn" rather than "can earned".  This is also true with "used to earn."  In general, when you use an auxiliary verb you inflect the auxiliary rather than the main verb.

Comment: @RobRodes, I also didn't say "can earned" is true, I just quote his sentence but in my own, I changed it to "earn"

Comment: @nima Your welcome, just please review my answer and the other answer, as your sentences need treatments.

Answer (score 1):

> She worked **so much** that she can earn twice as much as she used to.

Here "so much" indicates that she worked a lot.

> She worked with **such** diligence that she can earn twice as much as she used to.

Such indicates that she had a noticeable amount of diligence.

> She worked **such** that she can earn twice as much as she used to.

This usage is uncommon in my experience.

> Her work is **such** that she can earn twice as much as she used to.

This is more common but in my view is less refined. I avoid it myself.

Comment: *can* or *could*?

Comment: I only used "can" because the OP did. I'm having difficulty imagining a scenario where I would say this. But the question was on "so much" versus "such" so that's what I focused on.

Comment: @Ahmad Maybe better would be: "She worked so well that she could earn twice as much as she does." Could shows an unrealized possibility. Or: "She worked so well that she now earns twice as much as she used to." Now she has arrived. Using "can" doesn't make much sense because we don't know about that until she actually does. So I agree that "could" would probably be better. But it depends on the context.